# It is strange that / Strange that

Tags: adjectives, ellipsis

"Strange that they went outside without umbrellas. It's raining!"

Is this sentence grammatical? Do I need to say "It is strange that ..."?

In this "It is adjective that" structure, is omitting "it is" allowed?

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable in conversation, though it would be considered ungrammatical in formal writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is very common.

"Funny how..." "Interesting that..." "Weird to think..."

It's very normal in casual conversation.

Comment: Do we have a technical term on that, like fronting or what, so that I can look it up in my grammar book?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can also just say "Strange!" or "Weird!" if you see something odd; it's a common conversational usage that might not be appropriate in formal writing.

Comment: Since you mentioned casual conversation, I finally found it on Practical English Usage by Michael Swan, my favorite grammar book. Section 277, ellipsis at the beginning of a sentence, says we often leave out unstressed words at the beginning of a sentence.

Answer (score 3):

Like @bensalerno already said it is common and correct. Yes, there are words left out, but that is a common language device: it is called an *ellipsis*.

Under certain circumstances you can leave out words which are obviously implied. In this case it is the "*It is*", which - as you yourself noticed - should go in front.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ellipsis) defines "ellipsis" as:

> the omission of one or more words that are obviously understood but that must be supplied to make a construction grammatically complete

and gives the example:

> Begin when [implied: "you are"] ready.

The word "ellipsis" comes from the Ancient greek word "élleipsis (ἔλλειψις)", which means "to leave out". In typography an "ellipsis" is this: "..." (three dots, signifying there is something left out).

For a taxonomy of various forms of ellipses (yes, that is the plural) see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics))

See also these links for further examples and comments:
[Why is the subject omitted? (Stack Exchange)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66972/why-is-the-subject-omitted-in-sentences-like-thought-youd-never-ask) and [Dropping the subject (Language Tool)](https://languagetool.org/insights/post/dropping-the-subject/)